# How to prove that $ 1- \frac{x^2}{n} \leq (1+\frac{x}{n})^n\cdotp(1-\frac{x}{n})^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

How would I prove this inequality (assuming its true, its from a textbook)

$$1 - \frac{x^2}{n} \leq (1+\frac{x}{n})^n\cdotp(1+\frac{-x}{n})^n$$

if $n > |x|$, $x\in R$ and $n\in N$

I first rewrote the inequality to
$$1 - \frac{x^2}{n} \leq (1-\frac{x^2}{n^2})^n$$I then tried to manipulate the inequalities by saying the right hand side was greater than a smaller expression however I was unable to prove the above. I also tried induction where the base case works however I was unable to show that a case being true implies the next also being true.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Good first step. Now Bernoulli's inequality would help.

Comment: How would you use the Bernoulli inequality?

Comment: What does the Bernoulli inequality say? How can you relate that to the expression $\left(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2}\right)^n$?

Comment: So, $(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2})^n > 1 - n\frac{x^2}{n^2} = 1-\frac{x^2}{n}$ ?

Comment: Observe that the function $$ f (x)=(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2})^2-(1-\frac {x^2}{n}) $$ is increasing for all $|x|\ge n $.

Comment: No, $\left(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2}\right)^n < 1 < 1 + \frac{x^2}{n}$, unless $x = 0$. But Bernoulli's inequality says $(1+y)^n \geqslant 1+ny$ for $y \geqslant -1$, so what could you take for $y$ here?

Comment: I let $y = \frac{-x^2}{n^2}$ but I made a mistake is correct now?

Comment: Yup, now it's correct.

Comment: I made a typo. I mean show that function increasing for $|x|\le n $.

Answer (score 5):

$$1-\frac{x^2}{n}\overset{?}{\leq}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2}\right)^n$$
is a good starting point. You can assume $|x|<\sqrt{n}$, since otherwise the inequality is trivial, with the LHS being non positive and the RHS being positive.

Consider the logarithm of both sides. Then:
$$\log\left(1-\frac{x^2}{n}\right)\leq n\log\left(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2}\right)$$
is a consequence of the inequality:
$$\forall z\in[0,1),\qquad \log(1-z)\leq n\log\left(1-\frac{z}{n}\right)$$
that follows from the fact that:
$$\int_{0}^{z}\frac{dx}{1-x}\geq\int_{0}^{z}\frac{dx}{1-\frac{x}{n}}$$
since $(1-x)\leq 1-\frac{x}{n}$.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand why the last inequality is a Jensen's inequality.

Comment: @Shine: I modified my argument in order to avoid it, I think it is more elementary now.

Answer (score 0):

Deriving both sides on $x$, $$-\frac{2x}{n}\le-n\frac{2x}{n^2}(1-x^2)^{n-1},$$ or
$$-1\le-(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2})^{n-1}.$$
The latter relation is obviously true for $|x|<n$, so that the LHS of the initial relation decreases faster than the RHS, while they are equal for $x=0$.

(If you prefer, $l'(x)\le r'(x)\implies l'(x)-r'(x)\le0\implies l(x)-r(x)$ is decreasing $\implies l(x)-r(x)\le l(0)-r(0)=0\implies l(x)\le r(x)$.)

Comment: No you cannot differentiate the "inequality" (not equality) this is not true mathematically even your solution correct or not.

Comment: What if $C^1$ continuity is guaranteed ?

Comment: No. Example: it is well know that $\log (1+x)<x $ for all $ x>-1$, $ x\ne 0$. If you differentiate both sides we get $ \frac {1}{1+x}< 1$ for all $ x>-1$ which is not true take $ x=-1/2$

Comment: The logics goes the other way: $\frac1{1+x}>1$ for $x<0$, so that $\log(1+x)-x$ increases until $0$, where it equals $0$. Hence, $\log(1+x)-x$ is negative and $\log(1+x)<x$. I am not saying $f'(x)>g'(x)\implies f(x)>g(x)$, I am saying $f'(x)>g'(x)\implies f(x)-g(x)$ is increasing.

Comment: You wrote $\frac{1}{x+1}>1$ for $ x <0$, this is not true take $ x =-1-\frac {1}{3}$

Comment: Values $x\le-1$ are outside the domain (and if you considered $\log|x+1|$, you would be past the singularity, violating the $C^1$ assumption). Actually $C^0$ and differentiability should be enough.

Comment: OK, right.  But in your solution you said deriving both sides and kept the $\le $ " this false srarement". You cannot differentiate  any inequality.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16009/discussion-between-mwomath-and-yves-daoust).